# Configure or Query PlyQL(MySQL gateway)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

How to configure or query MySQL server through PlyQL(MySQL gateway) laguage?

I have followed the below link to know more about PlyQL and MySQL gateway, still i am not able to communicate or query MySQL server through PlyQL language.

https://imply.io/post/2016/05/04/programmatic-plyql.html

Can any share the steps to configure or communicate MySQL server through PlyQL language.

I have installed Node.js and then installed PlyQL in my macine. I am not able proceed after this.

Where i need to run **plyql -h your.druid.broker:8082 --experimental-mysql-gateway 3307** this command to start in a MySQL like server mode.

Thanks in advance.